# Spotify ios SDK Login: Invalid Redirect URI

Tags: ios, redirect, spotify

After I login into Spotify and connect it with my app, an error comes up saying:

> INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid Redirect URI.

I have registered my redirect URI with Spotify and ensured that it is the same one used in my code. I have created a URL type with the scheme from my redirect URI and a specific Identifier, but I am still getting the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to have the redirect URL on Spotify match exactly the url used in the code. If the two URLs are different, the app will not work.

In addition, be sure that all your URL schemes are correct. Normally the error occurs when a URL scheme or the redirect URL are not entered correctly.